# Issue while creating user account

Tags: bug

When I click Confirm and create this account in Database Administrators meta I am getting this error.

[image: Error page]

Actual problem is I clicked it second time.

Is there any feedback portal is available for post this kind of issues? This question is enough?

**Edit:**

I clicked **Confirm and create this account** button(I already have stackoverflow account), after creating my account I clicked browser back button, again that same page(Create this user page) appear, accidentally I clicked that button again.

Expectation: when I go back after creating my accouont, that button should not appear or on clicking that button should check whether user account created already or this is new user.